# Address.transfer(amount); What does it mean? who is recipient?

Tags: solidity

I have been learning solidity from yesterday.

One thing is so confusing to me.

```
address someone = msg.sender;
someone.transfer(10);
```

If you look at the code above. It is too ambiguous.

someone send 10 ether to X, who is X? It's not specified in the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
address someone = msg.sender;
someone.transfer(10);
```

`msg.sender` refers to the sender of the transaction/call.

`address someone = msg.sender;` Means that we store the sender address in the someone variable

`someone.transfer(10);`  This is the equivalent of `msg.sender.transfer(10)`
This function allows to send 10 ether from the smart contract to the sender address.

---

**EDIT for explanations:**

A smart contract is not very different from a "normal" address. It just can do more stuff (what you allowed it to do in the code). 
As a consequence, smart contracts can own ether (to be more precise, their address can), and they can behave like normal addresses. So a smart contract can send Ether to an address and receive ether too. However, you can tell the smart contract to do more stuff when it receives ether, check the keyword `payable` for more information.

To answer the question in the comment: no, this does not mean the smart contract owner(1) sends ether, but the contract itself, from its own ether balance.

(1) If this makes sense. A contract does not nativaly has an owner. This concept is only in the code of the contract.

---

**Personal note:**
However, I don't understand why you would duplicate the msg.sender address storing it into a variable. Optimisation is **very** important in solidity, so  use msg.sender and don't store it anywhere as it already is :)

Comment: Can you add more detail about "send 10 ether from smart contract to the sender address"?

Comment: Does It mean that the smart contract owner send 10 ether from his wallet to sender's wallet?

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it will help you!